# Which is the most important code analysis rule and why?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, coding-style, fxcop

A large set of code analysis rules is defined within [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264971.aspx) and [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429379%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) but which one do you find to be the most important and most critical to conform and why?

Retrospectively, could any of the rules have saved you a lot of time/money if you had enforced them from the start or at least before your product was released?

Answer (score 2):

[CA1031: Do not catch general exception types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)